# Best way to maintain huge amount of connections in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, http, tcp

I'm wondering wich is best solution for maintaining huge amount of small TCP connections in multi thread application without locking after some time.

Assume, that we have to visit lot of http web sites (like ~200 000 on different domains, servers etc) in multi thread. Wich classes are the best to do safest connection (I mean most lock-resistance, not multi-threading lock but TCP connection that will "not react for anything"). Will HttpURLConnection & BufferedReader do the job with setted connection and read timeout ? I saw that when I was using simple solution:

```
URL url = new URL( xurl );
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( url.openStream() ) );
```

All threads were locked/dead after 2-3 hours.

Is better to have constant threads like 10 running all-time and requesting URL's to take from main thread or better create one thread for each url and then kill it in some way if it will not respond after some time ? (how to kill sub-thread ?)

Comment: Are there "small" TCP connections?

Comment: I assume this is yet another web crawler? Have you looks at the source for some of the many which already exist?

Comment: I maen, that they should live no longer that 5-10 second and transmit no more than 100-200KB

Comment: @Peter Lawrey can you suggest me one, wich is written in way, that it will not lock up after seweral hours ? (i don't know any crawler)

Comment: In my experience, when this happens it because your application has exceeded the resources of your machine. Any software can do this if you don't have the right hardware.

Comment: But I mean a 5-10 threads and no special resources requirement. I Think that this is a problem with some servers that will no break connection or sth ? Both CPU & RAM usage, and number of TCP connections aren't huge when using it.

Comment: Consider using http://www.jboss.org/netty There is standard way to kill not responsive connections there.

Comment: @Ivan Sopov, succefully implemented netty in my project based on [this](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpClient.html) example, as far as I see it looks great (I don't understand everything but I see that handling connection works in jet another thread wich is interrupted on timeout). I will do bigger test and see if it will hung under bigger load.

Comment: There are two ways to handle connections in Netty - with blocking and non-blocking way. Is tested it here - https://gist.github.com/1120694 General recomendation is to use blocking IO if you have less than 1000 concurrent connections.

Comment: Great solution. Hard for begginer like me, but problem solved (with non blocking, did it before read last comment). Just added some timer to pipeline and never hungs.

Comment: @Ivan Sopov, post an answer, so i will accept that. Netty does great work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if it is going to be HTTP connection, I really doubt you can cache them. Because keeping the HTTP connection alive is not only at the client side, it requires the server side support too. Most of the time, the server will close the connection after the time out period (which is configured in the server). So, check what is the maximum time out configured at the server side and how long you want to keep the connection cached.

Comment: I don't want to keep connection. I want to disconnect I fast as I can, because each connection is connecting to other server (domain)

Comment: Sorry, I am confused here. You won't disconnect as fast as you can? So, when will you disconnect?

Comment: edited. I want to disconnect immediatly after page html is loaded. This problem is about some timeouts or TCP-connection locks when connectiong to some rare servers, wich causes that simple connection like in my example just hungs forever